# Implementing Facepile through FacebookGraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In one of my app, i need to load facepile with given url. For liking the post and other things related to Facebook, i am using Facebook SSO. Please anyone help me in loading facepile ?

Comment: Have you looked here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/ ? Also, using the Like button, there is an option to show Faces next to the button when users like your page, have you tried that as well - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ? If yes to both, then please elaborate your question.

Comment: actually for liking the post I used like the following way.....        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes",[resultDictionary valueForKey:@"id"]] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"DELETE" andDelegate:self];                how can i load facepile using the similar way how i did posts.. is it possible,even i tried ths one too -  developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile. but in vain